# Vor uns her fuhr ein roter BMW

Tags: grammar-identification

The following sentence in my grammar book. I am not able to determine whether the "ein roter BMW" is in nominative case or accusative case.

> Vor uns her fuhr ein roter BMW

Given translation

> A red BMW was driving along ahead of us

Comment: A look into the declension table for adjectives shows that in the case of masculine the ending -er can only be nominative singular or genitive plural. Genitive plural makes no sense here, so that leaves only nominative singular.

Comment: *Her* is the meaning 4 as given in [DWD](https://www.dwds.de/wb/her), i.e. "affirmation of a persisting state", and the word position is some unusual. I would put it to the end: *Vor uns fuhr ein roter BMW her*. One could also put the subject at the beginning as in your English translation, but the context may suggest otherwise.

Comment: Vor stressing reason I have no problem on word order. It is just far from straight forward, I just used it sometimes myself and had no understanding problem. example for declension table: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:rot

Answer (score 4):

Well, accusative would be

> eine**n** rote**n** BMW

And you would still need some nominative case as subject for a proper sentence.

So you are dealing with nominative, which here is also the subject of the sentence.